# React dynamically add image

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I am trying to add images dynamically from the assets folder in my react component. This is the code that I have:

```
import React from 'react';

const card = (props) => {
  const image = require.context(
    `../../assets/imgs`,
    true,
    new RegExp(`(${props.vnum}_${props.snum}.png)$`)
  );
  return (
    <div>
      <img src={image} alt="image" />
      <p>{props.english}</p>
      <p>{props.french}</p>
    </div>
  );
};
```

When I do this, I get the following error:

TypeError: **webpack_require**(...).context is not a function

I used CRA and looking up past posts I see that this should work. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: may be, the use of `createContext()` might solve your problem!

Comment: Have you found any solution for this??

Answer (score 0):

It's necessary to use it in those convention?

The simpler solution without **require.context()**

```
import React from 'react';
import Image from "../../assets/img/english
import Image from "../../assets/img/french

    const card = (props) => {
      return (
        <div>
          <img src={english} alt="image" />
          <p>{props.english}</p>

          <img src={french} alt="image" />
          <p>{props.french}</p>
        </div>
      );
    };
```

Also:

It's possible to add some conditional rendering here (depends on variable render english or french) - i'm not sure You need it.

**require.context** is a special feature supported by webpack's compiler that allows you to get all matching modules starting from some base directory. The intention is to tell webpack at compile time to transform that expression into a dynamic list of all the possible matching module requests that it can resolve, in turn adding them as build dependencies and allowing you to require them at runtime.

So if regex matches more than 1 element - mapping is needed - however i think in this specific issue import is enough.

Comment: Actually the reason I am using require.context() is because the image required will be dependent on the props being passed in, so I need it to recognize which image file to import on build

Answer (score 0):

This should be enough.

```
import React from 'react';

const Card = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <img alt="image" src={require(`../../assets/imgs/${props.vnum}_${props.snum}.png`} />
      <p>{props.english}</p>
      <p>{props.french}</p>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: I actually had tried this method as well but each time it is not able to find the module, I get an error in which it looks like it isn't checking the correct folder for the image: Error: Cannot find module './3_147.png'

Comment: In order for it to work the path must be in the `src` directory.

Comment: Yes the exact location of the image is src/assets/imgs/1_1.png for example

Answer (score 0):

you can use **simply require()**

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import Card from "./card";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello</h1>
      <h2>check this!</h2>
      <Card vnum={12} snum={13} english={"english"} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

card.js

```
import React from "react";

export default function card(props) {
  const image = require(`./img/${props.vnum}_${props.snum}.jpg`);

  return (
    <div>
      <img src={image} alt="image1" width="200px" />
      <p>{props.english}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

you can check this at here https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-ramanujan-5qwcp

Comment: I tried this however i get an error where it can't find the module: Module not found: Can't resolve './assets/imgs'

Answer (score 0):

This is not the exact anser for your question, but might help you in later scenes maybe you may already know about this. If you have got URL's of the image that can be grabbed from internet, then you can save them into an array. Eg: const array = ['url1', 'url2',....etc]

Then use : `array.map(url => { <img src={url} /> })`

Also if you are pulling from an API use the same method.